# can I listen to bacbone view changes in a model where the view was created?

Tags: backbone.js, view, model

I have a problem with backbone and i'm new in backbone so I'd like to ask for help here. I'm writing a single page application and i would need to listen to changes in a view from a model.

// I have this model where I create the view called Window( using require.js ) and I 'd like to listen to changes inside my view, but i could not make it happen. I have variables inside the Window.view like: shown. And i need to know if the shown changes to false. Is there a way to make it happen?

```
var Initialize = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            var SystemInfoWindow = new Window(this.toJSON());

            // 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't listen to views' attributes' changes, you can only listen to models' attributes' changes (thanks to the `listenTo` and `on` methods and such). What you can do however, is binding your view to some model that will have the wanted attribute, so you can listen to it. For example:

```
var Initialize = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    shown: false
  },  
  initialize: function() {
    var SystemInfoWindow = new Window({model: this});

    // and then
    someObject.listenTo(this, 'change:shown', someObject.someListener);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast and useful answer. I could make it working with your solution. Thank you :)